# JavaScript and Java in the same for loop, is this possible?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

In a JSP file I use the following code to add attributes to elements that belongs to a particular class :

```
    $($('.dhx_combo_input').get(0)).attr('style','width: 100%;<%=(highlight.get(0))?"background-color: #FF0000;":""%>');  
    $($('.dhx_combo_input').get(1)).attr('style','width: 100%;<%=(highlight.get(1))?"background-color: #FF0000;":""%>');  
    $($('.dhx_combo_input').get(2)).attr('style','width: 100%;<%=(highlight.get(2))?"background-color: #FF0000;":""%>');
```

`highlight` is an `ArrayList<Boolean>`.

I got many of those lines and only the index differ. It's not really pretty nor concise so
I tried to replace it with a for loop but I need the index to be used in JS and Java. I'm not sure that it's possible. Will I stay stuck with this syntax or is there a better solution?

**Edit :**

The loop has to be limited by the number of elements that belong to class `dhx_combo_input`.

Comment: side note: you could use `$('.dhx_combo_input').eq(0).attr` to ommit creating multiple jquery objects.

Comment: @h4b0 He has written what he tried/is using and is asking for a better way to do it. It seems the "what have you tried" becomes more of a reflex than a real question.

Comment: @Yoshi he's also asking about using the same index in Java and JS, he's not sure if that's possible - I was referring to this case.

Comment: @h4b0 Actually I've prefer not write the for loop I've tried because it was obviously wrong and it'd not make sense (don't want to affraid good web-dev with terrible code =) ).

Comment: @Yoshi Thanks for the tips, I'm not so aware of JQuery syntax! (James gave it also!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless I'm misunderstanding your question, you can do this:

```
<%
    for(int i=0;...){
%>

$('.dhx_combo_input').eq(<%=i%>).attr('style','width: 100%;<%=(highlight.get(i))?"background-color: #FF0000;":""%>');

<%
    }
%>
```

Note, I modified your jquery slightly to use `eq` instead of `get` so you don't have to call `jquery` twice.

Comment: (With the caveat that it'd likely be better to avoid the scriptlet and use JSTL instead.)

Comment: @James Montagne Thanks this solution works. I've just one more problem, the max limit in the for is in a JS var (the number of `$('.dhx_combo_input')`) can I use it in the for?

Comment: The java code in your jsp is run on the server side and has no way of accessing javascript variables client side.  However, these `.dhx_combo_input` elements are created server-side as well, so you must have some way of telling server-side, how many there are.

Comment: @JamesMontagne Thanks, it's what I understood too, hoping there is a trick btw. Anyway I will deal with that, thanks again!